# Passing Google Analytics cookies through form and a redirect across domains

Tags: google-analytics, cross-domain

My Google Analytics tracking cookies are not being passed across domains. Let me explain the situation.

Form on www.domainA.com.

Once the form is submitted, we take the submitted form info and store it in our database and then build a redirection url to www.domainB.com.

The redirect code:

```
function webform_submit($form, &$form_state) {
$level = array(
0 => 2603, // $50
1 => 2604, // $100
);
$type = array(
0 => FALSE,
1 => 'MEMORIAL',
);
$values = $form_state['values'];
$first_name = $values['submitted'][1];
$last_name = $values['submitted'][2];
$donation_level = $level[$values['submitted'][3]];
$donation_amount = '';
$donation_type = $type[$values['submitted'][11]];
$redirect = 'https://www.domainB.com/?id=formsubmit'.
'&set.FirstName=' . $first_name . '&set.LastName=' . $last_name .
'&set.Level=' . $donation_level . $donation_amount . $donation_type;
$form_state['redirect'] = $redirect;
```

I have tried adding the GA cross-domain form submission code `onsubmit="_gaq.push(['_linkByPost', this]);"` to the form on www.domainA.com but it's not working.  It's obviously getting caught up in this redirect we are doing.

Any ideas how I can pass the GA cookies through this redirect as well?

Answer (score 0):

`_linkByPost` works by appending GA cookie values to the form URL -- something like

```
?__utma=169676990.1952763064.1321288170.1329515418.1329517713.24&__utmb=169676990.1.10.1329517713&__utmc=169676990&__utmx=-&__utmz=169676990.1321288170.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)&__utmv=-&__utmk=10444341
```

In your server-side form processing, you can try adding those values to the www.domainB.com redirection URL.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  How would I go about doing that?  Do I need to explicitly pass through each variable, __utma, __utmb, etc.?

Comment: Yes -- probably the safest thing is to strip out the variables specifically from your form, and pass everything else through.